# How to combine multiple string vectors to create data structure in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been looking around but I have been unable to find a way to do this in R.

I have multiple vectors and I want to combine them to create a fixed data structure.

For example I have the following vectors:

```
year <- c("2019","2020")
month <- c("1","2"....)
country <- c("USA","GER","CAN"...)
```

I want to be able to create a dataframe that is structured as follows:

```
year    month      country
2019      1           USA
2019      1           GER
2019      1           CAN
2019      2           USA
....
```

I have looked around, but I have not found a way to create the desired result.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(year, month, country)
```

---

Or with `expand.grid` from `base R`

```
expand.grid(year, month, country)
```

Comment: Thank you! that is exactly what I needed.  I will mark it as a solution once the system allows it.